# Is there a problem with setting React.Component state equal to a this.props value in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to assign an object that is passed into a React.Component as a property to a state value like so,

```
state = {
    rota: this.props.rota
}

render() {
    // const { cleaning, chairs, creche, flowers } = this.state.rota;
    const { cleaning, chairs, creche, flowers } = this.props.rota;

    console.log(creche);
}
```

The commented out section where it get's the value of the state prints out an empty string, however the property values are correct. Am I doing something wrong when assigning the props.rota to the state.rota?

I am using typescript and have done exactly this in another place in my program - however the property being passed in was a value type (string) rather than an object type.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting that state? If it's inside the constructor, then the props are not initialized at that point, so that might be your issue. Try instead using `getDerivedStateFromProps` which is actually designed for this exact case (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: why would you want to do this if you pass down the props to the component either way? if you want a snapshot of props to state you can use componentDidUpdate(prev, next) { this.setState() }

Comment: @joelgullander `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. You should not use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually a bad practice.

Take your case.

You get a value as prop from a parent component.

The inner component will already be re rendered every time that this value changes in the parent component.

If you go with an approach like yours, what most probably you will do, is to change that value inside the inner component too (through state), whose changes will not be reflected on the parent component.

You are actually breaking the design pattern of uni directional data flow, on which react relies a lot on.

So my personal opinion is to lift up the state in this case and avoid such kind of situations. Use callbacks instead if you want to communicate changes to the parent, or use some state management (context, redux, etc..).

Or design a better solution using HOC or render props Components.

Comment: My reason being that this component is a modal input form - I'm passing in initial values for some of the texts boxes that may/may not be changed - when passing back changes I want to incorporate only the new changes and retain any unchanged values. In responded to you I have thought of a possible way of fixing this as I know props-state is an anti-pattern!

Comment: Use a callback passed from the parent component to the inner one, to be called when the modal will be closed passing the new values back to the parent. Then update the parent inside that callback

Answer (score 1):

Even though @quirimmo has pretty much answered your question, if you want to do this sometime in the future, the easiest way would be to use a constructor function and pass the props in as a param, and then just set that as the default value of the state

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             rota: props.rota,
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sure that the prop is actually available in the moment you want to set the initial state, since the constructor is the first function that is called in the component lifecycle.